# NEST API call getting 404 Not Found with good query

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, nest

I am querying a Elastic 5.4 instance with NEST and getting the following error.  I have all of the DebugInformation() and when running the query in DevTools in Kibana all is well and I get results.  I don't believe this is a timeout issue as the request appears to complete and give a response but would appreciate a second set of eyes on this.  Here is my Serilog output.  This is running a raw query using ASP.NET Core.  Thanks in advance for your help.

```
2017-08-24 10:48:58.723 -05:00 [Debug] ElasticController:Index
2017-08-24 10:48:58.921 -05:00 [Debug] ElasticService.QueryInstanceTail: elasticQuery { "bool": { "filter": [ { "term":  { "instance_num": "99999999" }}, { "range":  { "@timestamp": { "gte": "2017-08-22T15:48:00Z", "lte": "2017-08-22T16:48:00Z" } } } ] } }
2017-08-24 10:48:58.922 -05:00 [Debug] ElasticService.QueryInstanceTail: searchResponse 0 : Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful low level call on POST: /filebeat-%2A/_search
# Audit trail of this API call:
 - [1] BadResponse: Node: http://devserver.local:5601/ Took: 00:00:00.1976977
# ServerError: ServerError: -1Type:  Reason: "Not Found"
# Request:
{"from":0,"size":60,"query":{ "bool": { "filter": [ { "term":  { "instance_num": "99999999" }}, { "range":  { "@timestamp": { "gte": "2017-08-22T15:48:00Z", "lte": "2017-08-22T16:48:00Z" } } } ] } }
# Response:
{"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found"}
```

Comment: Are you making the request to the right port (9200) ? This definitely doesn't look like an issue with your query.

Comment: After posting I realized i had the port for Kibana in there instead of 9200 for elastic. #facepalm. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple bonehead error on my part. I had the Kibana port in the API connection string. However the return that NEST gives looked to me like it was successful but elastic returned the 404.  Just a note for anyone who may have this happen in the future.  Assure your connection string.